# XML -> XSLT using encoding UTF-8 doesn't work with Microsoft Excel - why?

Tags: excel, xml, csv, xslt, encoding

i have a problem with Microsoft Excel and my generated "Textfile - csv" / "Textfile - tab".

All application see the UTF-8 encoding and works with German umlauts (äöüßÄÖÜ).
Notepad++ (Windows 7) opens the file and shows all correct
Editor (Windows 7) opens the file and shows all correct
Only the ..... Excel opens the file (if you use it without import option dialog) with the wrong encoding and destroy all German umlauts.
I didn't find a option in the excel preferences to avoid this problem - maybe I'm blind or maybe Microsoft doesn't do a good job on excel.

Is there a way in XSLT to change anything, that excel will do the job correct (without the import option dialog - I know, this works, if you give them the encoding in this dialog)

Right is in the example "München" but excel gives me a wrong result. I can't post the excel result - gives an error in the input field.

I only work in XSLT 1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <table name="test">
        <row>
            <field attr3="name">München</field>
        </row>
    </table>
</root>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:value-of select="root/table[@name = 'test']/row/field[@attr3 = 'name']"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is saved as .txt in the file system.
I tried also formats like .csv and .tab - all doesn't work with excel -> but works always in notepad++/editor/....
Only the "import dialog" in excel gives the characters in the right form - but the users want to double click the file.

Comment: This has nothing to do with XSLT and everything to do with Excel. You can verify this by creating a new file in a text editor, typing `München` and saving it with UTF-8 encoding. Then see what you get when you open it in Excel.

Comment: Thx for you explanation -> But how to fix this? Am I'm the first person with this problem? Is There no workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know. I don't use Excel. I suggest you ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) (and leave the XSLT part out).

Comment: As for workarounds, you could try producing a file in the Excel 2002/2003 XML format and see if that works.

Comment: Open the file in Notepad++, change then encoding to UTF-8 with BOM, and re-save the file.  Excel assumes files without BOM are encoded in an ANSI encoding, which varies by locale.

Comment: To open and save it is no option - than the user also can use the "import option" instead - this is also a step in-between.

Answer (score 2):

Excel needs a BOM (Byte Order Mark) to correctly read UTF-8 encoded CSV. Unfortunately I don't know how to add BOM via XSLT when using version 1.0, but you can use some external application to do it as it's trivial task. I've written one myself a while back if you need a [reference](https://github.com/pczajkowski/bom).

Comment: the option of the bom is only available in XSLT 2.0 - but I have to use 1.0 - thanks for your link

Answer (score 0):

With an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet, [xsl:output](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-output) has the **byte-order-mark** attribute.

> The `byte-order-mark` attribute defines whether a byte order mark is written at the start of the file. If the value `yes` is specified, a byte order mark is written; if `no` is specified, no byte order mark is written. The default value depends on the encoding used. If the encoding is `UTF-16`, the default is yes; for `UTF-8` it is [implementation-defined](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-implementation-defined), and for all other encodings it is `no`. The value of the byte order mark indicates whether high order bytes are written before or after low order bytes; the actual byte order used is [implementation-dependent](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-implementation-dependent), unless it is defined by the selected encoding.

Change the `xsl:stylesheet` to `version="2.0"` and add `byte-order-mark="yes"` to the `xsl:output` (and obviously, use an XSLT 2.0 engine):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" byte-order-mark="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="root/table[@name = 'test']/row/field[@attr3 = 'name']"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, but ArminMuc mentioned "I only work in XSLT 1.0".

Comment: Understood. The answer may not help the OP if 2.0 isn’t an option, but others may have the same issue and this would be the easiest way to generate a CSV that Excel knows to read as UTF-8.

Comment: the problem is the limitation of XSLT 1.0 - I now, that it is available in version 2.0
byte-order-mark? = "yes" | "no"

The software I use, have only the XSLT 1.0, which is available in apache license (XALAN). As I know, there is no free XSLT 2.0 in apache license available.

Comment: Use Saxon-HE instead of Xalan. It’s a free Java based XSLT 2.0 engine